# How to move element from initial state to right and then from initial state to left?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

There is a hand icon that I am using on my page and It is directing to three images.I want an animation on this icon, where It should move from initial state to right, then from initial state to left and so forth.In other words, it should cover all the three images.
I have tried myself also, it is moving initial state to right but not from initial state to left.Here is my code snippet down below:

```css
div#skill .logos {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.logos>img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.move {
  position: relative;
  animation: move 2s infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}
/*Animation on hand*/

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 60px;
    right: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
    right: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="move center-block" src="img/icons/hand-finger-pointing-down.svg" width="60" height="60">
<div class="logos text-center">
  <img src="img/icons/adobe-photoshop.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="img/icons/bootstrap-4.svg" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="img/icons/Sublime_Text_Logo.png" width="50" height="50">
</div>
```

Please guide me and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted another answer with your exact mark up. You were using both right and left. When you're animating, you should make sure you're animating on the same property/properties, which in this case is left.

```css
div#skill .logos {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.logos, .move-container {
  max-width: 200px;  
}
.logos>img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.move {
  position: relative;
  animation: move 5s infinite;
}
/*Animation on hand*/

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 60px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  75% {
    left: 120px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 60px;  
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="move-container">
  <img class="move center-block" src="img/icons/hand-finger-pointing-down.svg" width="60" height="60">
</div>
<div class="logos text-center">
  <img src="img/icons/adobe-photoshop.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="img/icons/bootstrap-4.svg" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="img/icons/Sublime_Text_Logo.png" width="50" height="50">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main difference I think is that I was more specific with my animation. I specified that it should start from center, go to left, go back to center, go to right, then go back to center.

```css
.images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 30%;  
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.icon-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.icon-container img {
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: move 6s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {left: 50%}
  25% {left: 15%}
  50% {left: 50%}
  75% {left: 85%}
  100% {left: 50%}
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
    <img src="http://img06.deviantart.net/25de/i/2012/134/3/1/037_by_koko_stock-d4zq28i.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.apimages.com/Images/Ap_Creative_Stock_Header.jpg"/>
  <img src="http://platowebdesign.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/public-domain-images-free-stock-photos-light-sky-silo-windows-lillyphotographer-1024x684.jpg"/>
  <div class="icon-container">
    <img class="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/touch-gesture-outline/512/double_click_touch_click_finger_hand_select_gesture-512.png"/>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! but can you just please do it in a more easy way? as my css is totally different than yours and this is not working with me @zsawaf